# Perl and hash calculation

Tags: perl

When I'm execute this command in terminal

```
echo -n 1 | sha256sum
```

then command output looks as this:

> 6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b

But when I use perl script with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = '1';
my $hash = Digest::SHA->sha256_hex($text);

print $hash;
```

then script output looks as this:

> f3a94951713ca935dcac0422747fb3e435cd8c6785c91ff5d9477e573df9ca28

I think that problem is with string $text encoding when it goes to hash function. Can someone explain how I must do it correctly?

Comment: You're doing `Digest::SHA::sha256_hex("Digest::SHA", 1)`

Comment: Thanks to you all! `The Digest::SHA::sha256_hex` is works but not `Digest::SHA->sha256_hex`. Must read and learn more about this. :-)

Comment: You might want to check documentation of module, https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MSHELOR/Digest-SHA-5.92/lib/Digest/SHA.pm

Comment: @hiprivet: there's a good answer regarding `::` and `->` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19621873/2884483)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `Digest::SHA->sha256_hex(1)` because it's actually `Digest::SHA::sha256_hex("Digest::SHA", 1)`.

Use

```
 Digest::SHA::sha256_hex(1)
```

or

```
 use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);
 sha256_hex(1);
```

or (OOP-style)

```
Digest::SHA->new(256)->add(1)->hexdigest()
```