# Perl's "Package::->method()" (colon-colon-arrow) notation

Tags: perl, perlop

I was reading the [documentation for the `attributes` module](https://perldoc.perl.org/attributes) and came across a method call notation I've never seen:

```perl
use attributes ();
attributes::->import(__PACKAGE__, \$x, 'Bent');
```

The doc did not provide an explanation for this syntax.

On investigation, it seems `Package::->method()` is equivalent to `Package->method()` and `'Package'->method()`.

It also seems equivalent to `Package::method('Package')`, provided the method is not inherited.

**Question 0:** Is there any practical reason for using `Package::->method()` notation?

---

Edit: I found if you have a constant with the same name as a package, `Package::->method()` calls the package method, whereas `Package->method()` calls the method on the constant.

```perl
use constant Foo => bless {}, 'Bar'; # or just => 'Bar'

print Foo::->method(); # prints 'Foo method'
print 'Foo'->method(); # prints 'Foo method'
print Foo->method();   # prints 'Bar method'

package Foo;
sub method { 'Foo method' }
package Bar;
sub method { 'Bar method' }
```

Strangely, with `use warnings`, this script will give a "Bareword 'Foo::' refers to nonexistent package" warning but *will execute it anyway*, which just confuses me more.

Even more strangely, adding the line `Foo::method();` before the `Foo::->method()` line *gets rid of the "Bareword" warning*.

**Question 1:** Can someone please explain what's going on?

For posterity, this is Perl v5.38.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Package::->method` is a (very slightly) safer way of writing `Package->method`.

---

This is answered by the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj#Invoking-Class-Methods). [How does Perl parse unquoted bare words?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58263206/589924) is also relevant.

`Foo::` is equivalent to `"Foo"`, except it also checks if namespace `Foo` exists.

`Foo` also means `"Foo"`, but only if it doesn't mean anything else. It's exempt from strictures when before `->`, but there's otherwise nothing special about `Foo` here. So if you have a sub called `Foo`, and it will call that sub. If you have a constant named `Foo`, it will be used.

In summary,

- `Foo::->method` always means `"Foo"->method`.
- `Foo->method` usually means `"Foo"->method`.
- `Foo->method` could also mean `Foo()->method`.

From that, we derive the following reasons for using `Foo::`:

- By using `Foo::`, you avoid calling a sub by accident. (This includes constants.)

  The chances of this happening are incredibly small in practice. And it's something that would be found in testing, one hopes. But given the rarity of occurrences, it could be confusing were it to ever happen.
- By using `Foo::`, you signal that it's not a sub call.

  But that's already the presumption when you see something of the form `Foo->method`. It's more important to signal when it *is* a sub call (for example, by using `Foo()->method`).
- By using `Foo::`, you get better diagnostics if you forget to load the module.

  You get

  ```
  Bareword "Foo::" refers to nonexistent package at ...
  Can't locate object method "method" via package "Foo" (perhaps you forgot to load "Foo"?)` at ...
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  Can't locate object method "method" via package "Foo" (perhaps you forgot to load "Foo"?)` at ...
  ```

  Did I say better? That's just noisier to me.